# How to properly pass parameter in query string with redirect_to? (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, url-parameters, query-string

I'm building a contact form creation app with rails 4.

Users can create contact forms (called `Contactable` in app), which when submitted creates a `Contact` and redirects the contact to the URL the user specifies.

I'm trying to pass the contact's email address through the redirect as a query string.

With my current setup, the email does get passed in the query string but it loses the "@" symbol.

If a contact form is submitted with an an example email like john@website.com, the query string gets built like this...

```
http://website.com/?email=johnwebsite.com
```

As you can see, it loses the '@' character. How can I keep that @ character?

In the Contact controller's create function, here is how I'm building the query string...

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @contact.save
    if @contactable.redirect_url.present?
      format.html { redirect_to @contactable.redirect_url + '?email=' + @contact.email }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @contact }
    else
      format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: @contactable.thanks_message }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @contactable }
    end
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Show the `config/routes.rb` file please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not build urls manually by string concatenation, because some characters need to be encoded in valid urls. If possible use url helper that take parameters.

I do not know if this works (depends on the implementation of `contactable`):

```
@contactable.redirect_url(email: @contact.email)
```

If that is not possible ensure valid encoding yourself:

```
"#{@contactable.redirect_url}?email=#{ERB::Util.url_encode(@contact.email)}"
```